# c# label to receive information from private method(toolbox value)

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created a new form, in which I have a toolbox. When I press a button in that form, it should relay that information that has been entered by the user(toolboxbox value) to the main form, in which it should say that piece of information in a label.

Since the method to create that username from the toolbox is private, I cannot access it from any other way. Making it public does not seem to make a difference, neither does get,set (from the way I've been trying to atleast).

Picture that may help explaining it:

[image]

Code (in which to create user):

```
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Newuserform : Form
    {
        public Newuserform()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

            private void buttonCreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string uname = textboxUsername.ToString();
            }

            public void Unamecreate()
            {

            }

    }
}
```

Form1 Code (To receive created user):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void aboutToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Aboutform form2 = new Aboutform();
            form2.Show();
        }

        private void newLocalUserToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Newuserform formnewuser = new Newuserform();
            formnewuser.Show();


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a lot of options.

One way is to create an event and handle it in the main form.

```
public partial class Newuserform : Form
{
    //the public property
    public event EventHandler<string> UnameChanged;
    public Newuserform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonCreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         if (UnameChanged != null)
             UnameChanged(textboxUsername.ToString()); //fire the event
    }
}
```

Now, to "handle" the event, do the following in your main form:

```
private void newLocalUserToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Newuserform formnewuser = new Newuserform();

    formnewuser.UnameChanged += Handler;

    formnewuser.Show();
}

private void Handler (object sender, string Uname)
{
    // do something wit the new Uname.
}
```

**note**: recreating the Newuserform  will require to cleanup previous attached resources.